# Django email form paradox

Tags: python, django

I have run into an interesting error with django forms and a template view.

In my views.py if I include the following view I get an http 500 server error, but the email sends successfully

```
class ContactUsView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = "/"

    def form_valid(self,form):
        message = "{name} / {email_addr} said: ".format(name=form.cleaned_data.get('name'),email_addr=form.cleaned_data.get('email_addr'))
        message += "\n\n{0}".format(form.cleaned_data.get('inquiry'))
        send_mail(subject=form.cleaned_data.get('subject').strip(),message=message,from_email='sender@working.email.com',
                            recipient_list=['receiver@example.com'],
                            )
        return super(ContactView, self).form_valid(form)
```

If I change the above code to the following, I am redirected to the appropriate success page, but email fails to send, is there something that I am missing?

```
class ContactUsView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = "/"

    def is_valid(self,form):
        message = "{name} / {email_addr} said: ".format(name=form.cleaned_data.get('name'),email_addr=form.cleaned_data.get('email_addr'))
        message += "\n\n{0}".format(form.cleaned_data.get('inquiry'))
        send_mail(subject=form.cleaned_data.get('subject').strip(),message=message,from_email='sender@working.email.com',
                            recipient_list=['receiver@example.com'],
                            )
        return super(ContactView, self).is_valid(form)
```

I feel like there is something basic that I am missing but I am not certain what it is.

Comment: When in debug mode, what does the 500 page say? It should give you an error trace

Comment: The actual error maybe more helpful as it will show you where the exception is. Try setting debug to true to get the error!

Comment: well, now I feel foolish for not thinking of that sooner, once I enabled debug I was able to figure it out.  Thanks for the helpful reminder

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because once I re-enabled debug it was clear that I had spelling error in a different part of the code